Pytorch (pip or conda)
I recently installed Pytorch (pip package) and later found that I have already have a Pytorch (conda package). Now I am not sure which one to keep or if should keep both. Also I am a beginner so i am not sure how to proceed from here.
I just started learning ML and I heard that conda is better for it, though I'm not sure. Please help me

You can choose one of the two to install in your environment. Don't worry about which one to choose, just start with one and if it works, great! If not, try the other one
